# Get and store all changed values in data

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongoose, diff

I am trying to create an "activity log" type thing on my server.  I am using Angular and Mongoose on a node server.  What I am trying to achieve is compare the request body with data stored in the DB by doing a deep diff.

So, whenever an API is hit, I am running this function:

```
createActivityInformation(currentObject, updatedObject) {

        let information = [];

        function getChangedItem(currentItem, updatedItem, key, prop){

            if(!currentItem || !updatedItem) return

            // IF OBJECTS
            if(typeof(updatedItem) === "object" && !Array.isArray(updatedItem)){           
                for(let prop in updatedItem){
                    getChangedItem(currentItem[prop], updatedItem[prop], key, prop) 
                }
            }
            else if(Array.isArray(updatedItem)){
            }
            else{
                if(key != 'updatedAt' && (currentItem && updatedItem) && (currentItem.toString() !== updatedItem.toString())){
                    // CHECK FOR DATE - THIS IS ADDED BECAUSE DATES ARE COMPARED DIFFERENT THAN TO STRINGS
                    if(currentItem instanceof Date && !isNaN(currentItem)){
                        if(new Date(currentItem).getTime() != new Date(updatedItem).getTime()){
                            information.push({
                                'changeFrom': { key: key, value: currentItem, prop: prop},
                                'changeTo': { key: key, value: updatedItem, prop: prop}
                            })
                        }
                    } else {
                        information.push({
                            'changeFrom': { key: key, value: currentItem, prop: prop},
                            'changeTo': { key: key, value: updatedItem, prop: prop}
                        })
                    }                     
                }
            }
        }

        for(let key in updatedObject){
            getChangedItem(currentObject[key], updatedObject[key], key)            
        }

        return information;

    }
```

Essentially what I am trying to do is store the original data, and the changed data.  But I cannot seem to get it to work perfectly.  The method is supposed to do a deep diff to compare everything, but also exclude some fields, like for instance `updatedAt`, or `_id`.

I took a look at the npm package `deep-diff`, but that did not work.  That even compares the mongoose wrappers, but also compares for instance strings with booleans which then gets returned.  But I also want to save the current data as well as the updated data.

Is there maybe something else I can look at that might solve my problem?

**EDIT**
Normal objects, strings, and numbers are fine.  But nested objects, arrays and booleans seem to be giving me a hard time.

here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/xgpcm0h3/

Comment: why do you say it is not working? which cases have you tested exactly and what's the result?

Comment: Normal objects, strings, and numbers work fine.
Arrays and nested objects and booleans are giving me a hard time.  Working on a fiddle

Comment: for an array currently you have this: `else if(Array.isArray(updatedItem)){ }` empty, probably you'd need to loop through each item and call this function again recursively for each value, between old and new array.